# Permission to get events from Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

I am attempting to get events from a specific page, through a person who is administrator of the site and the host of the events. This will not work unless i make the administrator a tester on my Facebook App. Anyone who knows which permission i am missing?

I have the following permissions already:

- business_management
- manage_pages
- public_profile
- publish_pages
- user_friends

*EDIT*

[image]
Facebook API Explorer

[image]
Facebook API Explorer

[image]
Access Token Info

Comment: public_profile and user_friends are for user profiles only. the only relevant permission for this is manage_pages. with that one, you already get a page token. so does it work if you add the user as a tester or not?

Comment: Those i get as standard. However issue remains that manage_pages does not give me access to events

Comment: ok, then please add your code and the api response. we need some more information. you are trying with a page token, right?

Comment: Added API Explorer response and information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events:

> This is a restricted edge. You cannot request access at this time.

Facebook has restricted this to specific partners; as a normal 3rd-party app developer you can not get page events at this time.

Comment: That would still cause it to work when a person is "tester" on our app? Because that is the thing that threw me off

Comment: It won’t work under any circumstances, unless your app would happen to be one for which Facebook has given access to this feature.

Comment: As stated above, it works if i put the person as "tester" on the Facebook-app. But not, if they are not listed as tester (or another role) on the app

Comment: Well then that is not a permissions issue, but one of app review. You need to submit your app for review, before you can ask people that don’t have a role in the app for any of those permissions to begin with.

Comment: Although I would be surprised if this actually worked, because the documentation says different. But perhaps they still have an exception for events from the pages the user manages, and this applies only to public pages.

Comment: Everything was submitted and approved less than a month ago. It is live with all permissions.

Comment: Well that speaks even more to that it is not possible any more to get page events with regular 3rd-party apps …

Comment: oh, my bad, i thought that the events api would be up again. yeah, misorude is right, there is no way.

Comment: Well.. Not much to do then i guess.. That is quite horrible.

Thanks!